# The code "var location = xhr.getResponseHeader('Location');" stopped working

Tags: owin

I have this in the done handler for a $.ajax request I am doing:

```
var location = xhr.getResponseHeader('Location');
```

It is for a cross-domain request, and it used to work, but it stopped with a recent deployment.

It's returning null now. I still have access to both deployment and staging environments and have been inspecting requests to figure out what changed.

It seem that in the working environment, the following header is included:

```
Access-Control-Expose-Headers:Location
```

The backend is ASP.NET Web API v2.

When looking at changes, the only thing I can see that we changed was moving from HttpConfiguration Cors support to Owin Cors.

Before:

```
 var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*", "Location");
 configuration.EnableCors(cors);
```

After:

```
app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
```

Is there a way to set the Location header as exposed also with the Owin.UseCors?

Comment: Are you using any custom header specifications in your web.config? `<system.webServer> | <httpProtocol> |
  <customHeaders>'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found something similar in the Katana Repository and am giving this a try. It solved my issue adding the Location to ExposedHeaders.

```
var policy = new CorsPolicy
{
    AllowAnyHeader = true,
    AllowAnyMethod = true,
    AllowAnyOrigin = true,
    SupportsCredentials = true,

};
policy.ExposedHeaders.Add("Location");

CorsOptions = new CorsOptions
{
    PolicyProvider = new CorsPolicyProvider
    {
        PolicyResolver = context => Task.FromResult(policy)
    }
};
```